# How to apply json values from url to Bilevel Partition D3 layout

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

Third day passed and I can't manage to change the code of bilevel partition (or Sunburst) d3 to show my data.
I've implemented this layout https://github.com/samehelhakim/D3-saChart---Bilevel-Partition with following json code:

```
{
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "المصاريف",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Expense_1",
          "colour": "rgba(255, 148, 42)",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "ExpSubCat1_1",
              "size": 8,
              "colour": "rgba(255, 148, 42,0.95)"
            },
            {
              "name": "ExpSubCat1_6",
              "size": 15,
              "colour": "rgba(255, 148, 42,0.45)"
            },
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Expense_2",
          "colour": "rgb(255, 148, 42)",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "ExpSubCat2_1",
              "size": 10,
              "colour": "rgba(255, 148, 42,0.75)"
            },
            {
              "name": "ExpSubCat2_2",
              "size": 5,
              "colour": "rgba(255, 148, 42,0.65)"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

And here is my data from json, fetched from url:
[image]

So, I need to change that layout to accept my json data and add nodes to the circle, but here is what I managed to do, with no result... :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: '{{ url_for("diffs.api_domains", file_id=file.id) }}',
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(result, error) {

  partition
      .value(function(d) { return d.size; })
      .nodes(error)
      .forEach(function(d) {
        d.sum = d.value;
      });

      .value(function(d) { return d.sum; });

  var g = svg.selectAll("g")
      .data(partition.nodes(result))
      .enter().append("g");

  var path = g.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); })
    .on("click", click)
    .each(stash);
});
```

My data is added to the `result` parameter and I'm thinking that `d.name`, `d.size` and `d.value` must be replaced with the data parameters from my json, but don't know what changes I need to make...

If you have an idea of how to solve this, any hints or solutions would help me a lot. Please let me know if my explanations are unclear or if there is something that doesn't makes sense.